# How to convert a certain type of string into an array with keys in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, checkbox

I have a string of this type:

```
string(11) "2=OK, 3=OK"
```

from a text file. But I would like to convert it into an array of keys this type :

```
array (
 [2] => Ok
 [3] => Ok 
)
```

I was wondering how we could do that in PHP.

Note:- I normally use `explode()` and `str_split()` for the conversions string into array but in this case I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: A good start would be looking at `explode()`

Comment: I normally  use explode and str_split  for the conversions string into array but in this case I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) along with [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
<?php

$string = "2=OK, 3=OK" ;

$array = explode(',',$string);

$finalArray = array();
foreach($array as $arr){
    $explodedString = explode('=',trim($arr));
    $finalArray[$explodedString[0]] = $explodedString[1];
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZsNY8

Answer (score 0):

You can use default file reading code and traverse it to achieve what you want,

```
$temp = [];
if ($fh = fopen('demo.txt', 'r')) {
    while (!feof($fh)) {
        $temp[] = fgets($fh);
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
array_walk($temp, function($item) use(&$r){ // & to change in address
    $r = array_map('trim',explode(',', $item)); // `,` explode
    array_walk($r, function(&$item1){
        $item1 = explode("=",$item1); // `=` explode

    });
});
$r = array_column($r,1,0);
print_r($r);
```

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array
[array_map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) — Split a string by a string

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3ebb1f78d216123e3d5da4fbb1aab94272c331b).

Answer (score 0):

1. Explode the string by ',' symbol. You will get an array like ['2=OK', ' 3=OK']
2. Using foreach trim and explode each element by '=' symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` along with `array_combine`, `str_word_count`

```
$string = "2=OK, 3=OK" ;
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
$res = array_combine($matches[0], str_word_count($string, 1));
```

Output

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);

Array
(
 [2] => OK
 [3] => OK
)
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://3v4l.org/SlS8C)